# How to use launch4j with a Java custom runtime image?

Tags: java, java-9, java-module, launch4j, jlink

Is it possible to make a bundle/wrapper exe file with `Launch4j` with a modular java app?

The app is modular (jmods), exported with `jlink`, it doesn't generate any jar, but a `custom runtime image` (a few folders)  with a bat file that runs the command: `java -m package/path.to.class`

I read [Launch4j docs](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/docs.html), it sais jar tag is optional. Tried to use the program with the gui (it doesn't even enable the Run button) and with Windows cmd (*launch4j: Application jar doesn't exist.*)

**Edit 1:**

[This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54372647/create-a-java-standalone-executable-application-to-run-on-different-platforms-wi) is related to my question. Launch4j does not have this functionality yet.

**Solution** (until no other tool is capable to do so):

- Make the 7z file with the java custon runtime image:

  ```
  7z a "outputPath\fileName.7z" "inputPath\javaCustomImgFolder"
  ```
- Make a [config.txt file](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/sfx.htm) with these params:

  ```
  ;!@Install@!UTF-8!
  Title="Your app name" //dont know where it's shown.
  BeginPrompt="Do you want to install This Program?" //same
  RunProgram="your.exe" //7z automatically search a .exe
  Directory="bin" //play with the path if you need to
  ;!@InstallEnd@!
  ```
- Genearte the exe file:

  ```
  copy /b "path\7zS2.sfx" + "path\config.txt" + "pathTo\fileName.7z"   outputName.exe
  ```

**Note:** I needed the 7zS2.sfx (27kb) version file, which I've found [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sevenzip/files/7-Zip/9.22/7z922_extra.7z/download) by reference of [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8087595/what-is-the-difference-between-7zips-7z-sfx-and-7zsd-sfx). Other versions didn't make the job for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, none of the exe building tools predating the Java modules has caught up yet.

In case of Launch4j, there’s [a feature request](https://sourceforge.net/p/launch4j/feature-requests/129/), but there is no visible progress report. So we can only guess when it will be done.

But since `jlink` can create a bundled app with launcher script, a generic generator for self extracting archive files, like WinZip or 7zip, see also [How do I make a self extract and running installer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27904532/2711488), could be sufficient.

These generators for self-extracting archives usually also allow to specify a program/script to run after extraction, so when we archive the bundled application and specify the launch script, we get an exe file that can run a bundled modular Java application with a double-click. Which is the best we can get so far, until better solutions arrive.

Comment: Indeed. I ended up using 7z to make a runnable (not installer) exe.